# How to update a Webflux object from repository and save it back

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to 1) get an object from my repository, 2) update that object and then 3) save it back.

I've already done first two things:

```
fun updateUniversity(id: ObjectId,
                     newName: String,
                     newCity: String,
                     newYearOfFoundation: Int): Mono<University> {
    return universityRepository
        .findById(id)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(NoSuchElementException()))
        .map {
            if (newCity.isNotEmpty()) it.city = newCity
            if (newName.isNotEmpty()) it.name = newName
            if (newYearOfFoundation != -1) it.yearOfFoundation = newYearOfFoundation
            return@map it
        }
}
```

But I can't save the result. If I try to save my object through map `.map{ universityRepository.save(it) }` I get an error Type Mismatch, cause it returns Mono in Mono.

`.then{ universityRepository.save(it) }` also is not my case, because I need to pass a value (which I don't have) in save function.

I can call `.block()` but it smells too.

So could anyone show what the last line should be to save my updated object back in the repository?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that to save an object we need to use `.flatMap` not just `.map`. Because `.map` just transforms elements and `.flatMap` converts them to new **Publishers**.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

Comment: this is basic reactive and is covered in the getting started section of the official reactor documentation.